# How do I add elements to a vector of objects and print them?

Tags: c++, object, vector, printing, iterator

Our teacher told us to create a vector of objects and perform operations on it, but I couldn't understand how to properly do that: I tried to make a simple project with minimum data so that I could know what I was doing.

I have this class

```
class Obj {

    private:

        int num;

    public:

        Obj();

        void setNum(int nuovo_num);
        int getNum();

};
```

And then this one, with a vector of Obj

```
class VettObj{

    private:

        vector<Obj> vett;

    public:

        VettObj();

        void setVett();
        void stampaVett();

};
```

My initial thought was to use an iterator but I was just making a total mess and, with almost useless research, I decided to use a common integer counter.

I found that I shouldn't write anything in the VettObj costructor, as it automatically initialize stuff, so I left it blank.

The method that adds elements is this

```
void VettObj::setVett(){


    Obj temp;
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while(i < 5){


        temp.setNum(10);

        vett.push_back(temp);

        i++;
    }

}
```

And the one that prints elements

```
void VettObj::stampaVett(){


    int i;

    i = 0;
    while(i < 5){

        vett[i].getNum();

        i++;
    }

}
```

When I compile, everything goes well, but when I run the program I get nothing on the screen. I don't want to use mostly vector functions(if not necessary) as I saw that a lot of people can do it like this. I would really like to know how to do it with iterators too. Help pls ????

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Ask a **specific** question. The detailed background story of your program's origin does not have anything to do with anything.

Comment: you should probably start with a "Hello World". Why do you think in your program anything would be printed on the screen? It does not magically read your mind and does what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not actually printing anything in the stampaVett() method.
You could try with:

```
void VettObj::stampaVett(){

    int i = 0;

    while (i < 5){

        std::cout << vett[i].getNum();

        i++;
    }

}
```

I'd also suggest using English for method or variable instead of Italian, since SO is an international community.

Comment: Yes, that's it: in the end, the research I've made was not useless. Thank you.